# How to interpolate a vector more than a hundred nodes into percentage in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a vector with more than a hundred nodes (let's say 120), and I have the corresponding time to them as well.

```
data = [120x1];
Time = [0:0.01:(120/100)-0.01]';
```

Now, I want to convert the data into percentage.

```
percent = (0:0.01:(101/100)-0.01)';
```

When I use this command, it just cuts the data off at the 101th point instead of interpolating them.

```
IntpData = interp1(Time, data, percent, 'spline');
```

How do I interpolate the data (N nodes) into percentage (101 nodes)?

Comment: Please ask an actual question, not "can you help me". See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Adriaan I edited that! Now, can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert to percentage, but the time ranges from 0 to 1.2.
This means you want to rescale the data from 0 to 1. You only need to change the time-axis, but be sure that it has an equal amount of points as your data.

In this case

```
Time = linspace(0,1,120);
```

Would do this.

Comment: Time ranges from 0 to 1.2 with the step of 0.01 s! I need to interpolate those 120 nodes into percentage (101 nodes). I do not want to rescale, I want to show the data in percentage, which means it need to rescale the whole data (but it should keep the pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

To define Percent, we need to use the last point of Time instead of 101!
In this case, the last point is 1.2. So, Percent would be like this:

```
Percent = [0:(1.2/100):1.2]
```

Then, the command would return the interpolated data for a hundred points!

```
IntpData = interp1(Time, data, percent, 'spline');
```